# How do i get an variable based on id in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using fullcalendar. currently im developing draggable events but i would like to set the background-color based on the id of the event.

Html(draggable event part)

```
<div id='external-events'>          
    <h4>Versleepbare afspraak</h4>
    <? if ($colors !=null) : foreach($colors as $row) : ?>
       <div class='external-event' id="<?= $row->id; ?>" style="background-color:<?= $row->colortag; ?>" ><?= $row->soort; ?></div>
    <? endforeach;endif; ?>
    <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' /> <label for='drop-remove'>verwijder afspraak na plaatsen</label>
</div>
```

fullcalendar.js(droppable event part):

```
droppable: true, 
drop: function(event, start, allDay, delta) { 

    var title = $("div.external-event").text();
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    var color = $('#id').css('background-color') ;
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    console.log(event);
    copiedEventObject.start = start;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    console.log(start);
    $.ajax({       
        url: "../testcalendar/fullcalendar/add_events.php",
        data: 'title='+ title +'&start='+ start +'&idWerknemer='+ '20' +'&color='+ color,
        type: "POST",
    }); 
},
```

add_events.php:

```
<?php
// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$idWerknemer = $_POST['idWerknemer'];

// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blackboks-calendar', 'root', 'root');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, idWerknemer, color) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :idWerknemer, :color)";
$test = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer) VALUES (:idWerknemer)";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$qo = $bdd->prepare($test);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':idWerknemer'=>$idWerknemer, ':color'=>$color));
$qo->execute(array(':idWerknemer'=>$idWerknemer));

?>
```

i would like to set the color based on the id. the id's in the database currently are 1,2,3 but how do i set the color based on the id? because im using an foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the problem.Of course you can just set the colors by using `#1{ background-color #F00;}` in your CSS, but that is probably not what you are asking?...

Comment: unfortunately not:(. i get the colors from a table in the database. but i would like to set the same color to the dragable events i put in the fullcalendar

Comment: There was I case like this, when I just echo'd the CSS from php as well. You can do that inline, and then use the same colors as the dragable events?